# Is it considered the bug of both GCC and Clang for the sequence of copy-initialization of the result of a call?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Please see this [example](https://godbolt.org/z/rb59K31qz)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct A{
    A(){
        std::cout<<"A constructed\n";
    }
    ~A(){
        std::cout<<"A destroyed\n";
    }
};
struct B{
    B(int){
        std::cout<<"B constructed\n";
    }
    ~B(){
        std::cout<<"B destroyed\n";
    }
};
struct C{
    C(){
       std::cout<<"C constructed\n"; 
    }
    ~C(){
        std::cout<<"C destroyed\n";
    }
    bool operator==(B const&){
        return true;
    }
};
struct D{
    D(bool){
        std::cout<<"D constructed\n";
    }
};
bool fun(){
    A a;
    C c;
    return c==0;
}
int main(){
    D d = fun();
}
```

The outputs of the above example are identity in both GCC and Clang, they are that

```
A constructed
C constructed
B constructed
B destroyed
C destroyed
A destroyed
D constructed
```

That means the copy-initialization of the result of the call is sequenced after all the destruction of the local or temporary variable of that function. It contradicts with the following rule, which is
[[stmt.return#3]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/stmt.return#3)

> The copy-initialization of the result of the call is **sequenced before** the destruction of temporaries at the end of the full-expression established by the operand of the return statement, which, in turn, is sequenced before the destruction of local variables ([stmt.jump]) of the block enclosing the return statement.

According to the rule, the output should be that

```
A constructed
C constructed
B constructed
D constructed
B destroyed
C destroyed
A destroyed
```

Is it a bug of GCC and Clang?

Comment: Define your own class MyBool and use it as a return type for `fun()`. The class needs to be constructible from `bool` and convertible (castable) to `bool`. Then see whether the returned object creation gets sequenced before or after the params' destruction.

Comment: @CiaPan Thanks. You reminded me that the result object of the call is just the parameter of the constructor of `D`. The standard only guarantees the sequence of that parameter rather than the complete initialization of object `d`. https://godbolt.org/z/r3jdd9aTn

Comment: That's right. The `d` variable is irrelevant and it needn't even be explicitly declared. One may use the returned object to directly initialize a param to another function, like `gun(fun())` or use it immediately as some action performer and abandon it: `fun().doSomething();`. The rule you quoted applies anyway in all those cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return value from the function in question is a `bool`. This is what gets returned.

Your logged output shows no evidence of when the copy-initialization of the `bool` return value was sequenced, before or after anything else.

It also happens to be true that once the `bool` value is returned, the caller uses it to construct a new instance of `D`. But this is something completely unrelated to the copy-initialization semantics of the returned `bool` value from the function call.

Comment: the function call expression is a prvalue, hence the result object(`d`) is copy-initialized from the operand of the return statement, as per "the return statement initializes the glvalue result or prvalue result object of the (explicit or implicit) function call by copy-initialization from the operand."

Comment: Correct, and the temporary `bool` expression in `main()` was initialized accordingly to what you've quoted. And after that happened that `bool` result of the expression gets used to construct a new instance of `D`. The constructor of `D` cannot be called until its `bool` parameter is evaluated. Therefore, it will require violating a few fundamental rules of physics of our shared universe in order to reverse the flow of time and be able to construct an object before its constructor's parameter is evaluated.

Comment: I don't understand your meaning. In my mind, it looks like `d.operator==(c==0)`. Anyhow, there's no temporary object of type bool in this example. Why do you say there is a medium object?

Comment: The value returned from `fun()` is `bool`. It is not `D`. There is no existing `D` object, and there is no `d.operator==` that's getting invoked. A `D` object does not get created until ***after*** `fun()` returns. Which part of that is unclear to you?

Comment: I'm just wrong in the above comment. D::D(bool) will be called for copy-initialization of `d`. I see what the temporary object of type bool you said here, it's just the parameter of `D::D(bool)`, the rule only guarantees the sequence of the copy-initialization of the parameter.

Comment: Correct, only the copy-initialization of the parameter is sequenced like that. And you can't call the constructor until its parameter is initialized. Therefore it is logically impossible for `D` to be constructed until after `fun()`'s return value is copy-initialized.

Comment: I see. you may mention which object is it in this example that its sequence of the copy-initialization is guaranteed by the standard if you would like.